# cloudflare pages github Installation on this account is prohibited

Tags: cloudflare, github

I want to deploy a static html website that I have in my `github.com` repo to Cloudflare Pages.  So I logged into Cloudflare, then I went to `Workers & Pages>Pages>Connect to Git>Github` as shown in this image

[image]

But then I just see this:

[image]

Which says "Installation on this account is prohibited".  A few of my friends also ran into the same problem when they try to connect Cloudflare to their github accounts.

I can't find any documentation explaining how to get around this problem.  Does anyone know what I did wrong?